# Using cfldap to add users to the AD

Tags: active-directory, coldfusion, ldap

I keep getting this error when trying to add users to the AD via cfldap:

An error has occured while trying to execute query :[LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0910DA, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v4563 ].

This is my code:

```
<CFLDAP
    SERVER="<my server>"
    USERNAME="<my account>"
    PASSWORD="<my password>"
    ACTION="ADD"
    ATTRIBUTES="Name=t.test123abc; 
            SamAccountName=t.test123abc; 
            UserPrincipalName=t.test123abc@test.edu; 
            Email=t.test123abc@test.edu; 
            DisplayName=Test Test123abc; 
            Path=""OU=DomainUsers, DC=test, DC=edu""; 
            Enabled=true; 
            GivenName=Test; 
            Surname=Test123abc;
            EmployeeNumber=123;
            Description=03-25-2021;"
    DN="CN=t.test123abc,OU=DomainUsers,DC=test,DC=edu"
>
```

What is it complaining about?  What is making it so unhappy?

Comment: Strictly guesses but there are two possibilities.  One is that the date format is incorrect.  See if "03-03-2021" works better.  The other is the semi-colon after the final attribute.  Maybe another attribute is expected.

Comment: Or, it could be the two sets of quotes in your path attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but none of them worked.  :-(

Comment: I agree with Dan. I think it's probably the double quotes. Looking up the error codes, it seems to indicate that one of the attributes is empty, which would go along with it trying to interpret `Path=""` incorrectly. Maybe try single quotes.

Comment: Or possibly the final attribute `Description=.....;`. The semi-colon is a delimiter in the attributes, and since nothing comes after it, CF may be interpreting that as an empty attribute.

Comment: I did try both.  I can't remove the double quotes and replace w/ a single double quote as that terminates the string.  But I did try simply removing all quotes from the Path attribute as well as trying a single quote and both tries failed.  I also did try removing the last semi colon after the description attribute and it also had no effect.  I also tried just removing the Path attribute (to no avail).

Comment: If this were my problem I would go for the good old process of elimination.  Specifically I would determine the minimum set of attributes required to add a record, and try to add one.  Assuming I succeed, I would add one attribute at a time until I throw an error.